# Is __builtin_prefetch safe to be call with nullptr

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, prefetch

Suppose we have linked list and code like this:

```
void play_with_list(struct int_list *list) {
 while (list != NULL) {
 __builtin_prefetch(list->next);
 do_something(list->n);
 list = list->next;
 }
}
```

On the last iteration, __builtin_prefetch will be called with nullptr, because list->next is nullptr.

Is that safe?

Second part of the question - suppose list data is pointer to C string (char *) allocated on the heap. Will it be beneficial if I prefetch it too?

Comment: _"...Data prefetch does __not generate faults if addr is invalid__, but the address expression itself must be valid. For example, a prefetch of p->next does not fault if p->next is not a valid address, but evaluation faults if p is not a valid address...."_ https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looked for it, but never found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RichardCritten wrote in the comment above - by definition, it will not generate a fault. That much is guaranteed by the ISA. However, that doesn't meant it's entirely safe: there was a known performance penalty on Intel CPUs for prefetching address 0.

Intl optimization guide itself states:

> Prefetching to addresses that are not mapped to physical
> pages can experience non-deterministic performance penalty. For example specifying a
> NULL pointer (0L) as address for a prefetch can cause long delays.

(taken from [here](https://cdrdv2-public.intel.com/671488/248966-046A-software-optimization-manual.pdf), chapter 9.3)

However, you are probably a little bit safer as of Skylake since at least some of the penalty was fixed. Section 2.6.3 states that one of the changes there was:

> Reduced performance penalty for a software prefetch that specifies a NULL pointer.

Comment: Thanks for clarify that. I did some tests earlier and i was sur this is correct behaviour, except i was not able to find it into the docs